# How to watch for data changes in VueJS after data is loaded from server?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch

When my Vue component is loaded, it fetches some data from server and place it in the component data:

```
 data: function(){
    return {
        data: null,
        dataChanged: false,
    }
 },
 created: function(){
     // fetch data from server
      this.data = server_data
 }
```

Now I want to watch for its changes, and set a bool `dataChanged` when it's changed:

```
watch: {
   data: function(oldVal, newVal) {
       this.dataChanged = true
   }
}
```

The problem is, when data is initially loaded in `created`, it also triggers the watcher.

How do I watch for changes **AFTER** its initialization?

I have tried resetting `dataChanged` to `false` right after initialization, it doesn't work:

```
created: function(){
     // fetch data from server
     this.data = server_data
     this.dataChanged = false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try if the value of `data` is `null` then it's false;

```js
watch: {
  data: function(oldVal, newVal) {
    if (this.data == null) this.dataChanged = false
    else this.dataChanged = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change `dataChanged` in the watcher like this

```
watch: {
  data(newValue, oldValue) {
   if(oldValue !== newValue) 
    this.dataChanged = true;
   else
    this.dataChanged = false; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question:

- Problem: The watcher function gets called when data is initially loaded.
- Objective: Ignore initial change (when data is initially loaded) but run on all subsequent changes.
- Solution: Use a flag in your async operation.

Example:

```js
data: {
  items:[],
  isDoneLoading: false
},
watch: {
  items(){
    if(!this.isDoneLoading) return
    // runs only after data is done loading.
  }
},
methods: {
  async loadItems(){
     const { data } = await this.$http.get('/examples')
     this.items = data
     const setFlag = () => this.isDoneLoading = true
     await setFlag()
  }
},
mounted(){
  this.loadItems()
}
```